# Adding folding marks to Print Layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing, paper

Is there any way to automatically add folding marks to Print Layouts in QGIS?

I want to print maps on A0 size and need markers for folding to A4 size, like you can do in most CAD software for plans and maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do folding marks automatically, sadly.

My manual solution was laborous to create, but once saved to the templates, very helpful. I'll retrace the process for an A2 sheet (841 mm x 594 mm).

1. You need to create a horizontal line at the top (or bottom) of you
   layout, which is exactly as long as your sheet is wide. I created it
   from right to left, since you start folding at the right and thus
   measuring is easier. Be prepared for some knots in your brain
   nonetheless. You might have to factor in that your printer/plotter
   doesn't print borderless, so maybe add some space for cutting
   (rightclick the canvas and choose `page properties/settings`).
2. Then enter the properties of your line. First make sure it is
   exactly as long as it should be. Doubleclick the `main properties`
   of the line, the dialogue should look like below.

[image]

3. Hit the green plus to add a new linestyle. Set it to `marker line`,
   change the markers from dots to `line`. Then return to the marker
   line dialogue and change the placement to `first node only` and for
   `move node along the line` by 190 mm.
4. Duplicate this line style (the white-grey rectangle with the yellow
   asteriks at the bottom right). For this new marker line, change the
   `move along line` to 380 mm.
5. Repeat for 505 and 631 mm.
6. Next step: copy the line and paste it at the top/bottom - whichever
   you haven't created yet.

Repeat the process for the sides, using vertical lines. Measuring from the bottom, move your markers along the line for 297 mm.

For the other sheet sizes you'll find the measurements online.